# Probability of the Range of a Uniform Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

[image]

I am currently struggling with the fact that the answer in the back of the text states this probability is $\frac{5}{16}$, but I got $\frac{1}{2}$ using a transformation method and using the cdf method for the order statistics $Y_1$ and $Y_n$.

CDF Method:

The joint pdf of $Y_1$ and $Y_4$ is

$g_{1,4}(y_1,y_4) = \frac{4!}{(1-1)!(4-1-1)!(4-4)!}(F_{X}(y_4)-F_{X}(y_1))^{4-1-1} = 12(y_4-y_1)^2.$

Then the probability is:

$P(Range\{X_i\} < \frac{1}{2}) = P(Y_4 - Y_1 < \frac{1}{2}) = P(Y_1 < Y_4 < Y_1+\frac{1}{2}) = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{y_1}^{y_1+\frac{1}{2}} 12(y_4-y_1)^2 dy_4dy_1 = 12\int_{0}^{1} \int_{y_1}^{y_1+\frac{1}{2}} y_4^2-2y_4y_1+y_1^2 dy_4dy_1 =12 \int_{0}^{1} \left[\frac{y_4^3}{3} - y_4^2y_1 + y_4y_1^2\right] \Bigg{|}_{y_1}^{y_1+1/2} dy_1 = 12\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{3}\left(y_1+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\left(y_1+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2y_1+\left(y_1+\frac{1}{2}\right)y_1^2-\frac{1}{3}y_1^3+y_1^3-y_1^3 dy_1 = \ldots = \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be
\begin{align*}
&P(Y_1 < Y_4 < \min\Bigl(Y_1+{\small{\frac{1}{2}}},1\Bigr)\\[4pt] 
=&
\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\int_{y_1}^{y_1+\frac{1}{2}} 12(y_4-y_1)^2 dy_4dy_1
\;+\;
\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\int_{y_1}^1 12(y_4-y_1)^2 dy_4dy_1
\\[4pt]
=&
\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{16}
\\[4pt]
=&
\frac{5}{16}
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: Why should it be this? Is it because if $Y_1+1/2$ exceeds $1$ then our pdf is just zero?

Comment: If $Y_1 > 1/2$, then $Y_4$ can't reach $Y_1+1/2$.

Comment: Oh ok, I see. If $Y_1 > 1/2$, then $Y_4$ will never reach $Y_1+1/2$ since the max value that $Y_4$ can take is $1$ but $Y_1 + 1/2 > 1$?

Comment: Right.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Ok, this makes complete sense now. I just did not really think of the case $Y_1 > 1/2$

Answer (score 0):

both rv's are bounded in $(0;1)$ thus the area to be integrated is the purple below

[image]

Easy find $\frac{5}{16}$ doing 1 less the integral over the upper white triangle

$$1-12\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}dx\int_{x+\frac{1}{2}}^1[y-x]^2dy=...=\frac{5}{16}$$